# What does "leftmost" mean in that definition?

Tags: java, exception

[JLS at the 14.20.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1) says:

> If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with (§5.2) a
>   catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement,
>   then the first (**leftmost**) such catch clause is selected.

What is leftmost? We put catch clauses from top-to bottom as, for instance:

```
try{ }
catch(IndexOutOfBoundException e){ }
catch(SQLException e){ }
catch(NullPointerException e){ }
//etc
```

Comment: This is not related to any new features introduced in later Java versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with any new language features of Java.

The term "leftmost" pertains simply to the earliest-occurring catch clause. Picture the code as a one-dimensional sequence of tokens, extending from left to right. That is how the language parser sees it.

Therefore all that stipulation states is that the first matching catch-clause is entered.

Comment: You mean if an exception is thrown the first catch-block that can handle the exception will be selected, right? Is that concept doesn't relate to the the multi-catch clause?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, the semantics explained by that sentence have been in Java since version 1.0.

Comment: @assylias While I wrote "picture it", you actually painted the picture :)

Answer (score 4):

Technically your example could be written:

```
try{ } catch(IndexOutOfBoundException e){ } catch(SQLException e){ } catch(NullPointerException e){}
```

Leftmost simply means first in program order.

ps: it has nothing to do with multi catch exceptions and the wording can be found in the [3rd edition of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.20) too although there was no multi catch concept yet.

Comment: The standard is just a bit uncler in that moment. By now I understandm thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have quoted the JLS which is perfectly valid for version higher than 6.

There is no `leftmost` in the code cited in your question.

For Java 8 - there is different syntax for for exception handling.

For example - you can do some thing like

```
 catch (Exception one | Exception two | Exception three) {
  // handling part
 }
```

here, the left most is `Exception one` and the `quote` can be validated with the above syntax.

**Edit- I amend.**

It has nothing to do with the `catch` syntax introduced in Java 7 or higher versions.

`leftmost` means the catch block encountered first and which matches the exception type `thrown`.

For example

```
try {
   throw E1;
} catch (Exception E1) {}   //1
  catch (Exception E2) {}   //2
  catch (Exception E3) {}   //3
```

For the above code, `leftmost` catch block is at `1`.

Please feel free to comment and share you knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

we can convert following

```
try{ }
catch(IndexOutOfBoundException e){ }
catch(SQLException e){ }
catch(NullPointerException e){ }
```

To

```
try{ } catch(IndexOutOfBoundException e){ } catch(SQLException e){ }catch(NullPointerException e){ }
```

Now you can see what is the left most. In other words we can say earliest-occurring `catch` clause.

since `Java` 7 we can clearly say this. Because we can write multiple `catch` as

```
  try{ }
  catch(IndexOutOfBoundException |SQLException |NullPointerException e){ }
```

Now it is more clear.

Comment: Is this answer correct?  Can anyone confirm ? If so that would really save me some typing catching sub type of exceptions ?

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa You can use multi catch in Java 8 but the specific sentence you mention has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa yes it is completely correct. ohh why +3 and `-3`?